# XML isn't getting style information

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

Chrome's inspector says I am having Namespace trouble and that I am going off domain to get the styles. I don't understand what is wrong. I have been doing this for days! Here is the header sections from each file.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone = "no"?>
<!DOCTYPE toc SYSTEM "IoT.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="IoT.xsl"?>
<toc
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com toc.xsd">

    <supsectionI>
***OTHER CODE has been deleted to save space***

</toc>
```

**The XSL file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>.....
```

The DTD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="toc">
```

[Image of Errors in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlOQK.png)

Comment: There is nothing said about namespaces in the Chrome error console, it simply shows that you seem to be loading the files from the local file system and in that case it is known that Chrome by default disallows any loading of referenced stylesheets, so either load files over HTTP (e.g. with a local HTTP server) or start Chrome with the right command line options (`--allow-file-access-from-files`) to enable local file system access.

Comment: I meant "Domain", my mistake. no matter if I use an URI or URL it still complains about access to the DTD and XLS file. Firefox displays the xml text as a big block of text so I know it's not getting the style. Am I declaring wrong?

Comment: There are various oddities in your code like using `version="2.0"` in the XSLT although you seem to expect to run it in a browser like Firefox or Chrome which are all known to only support XSLT 1.0. And the use of `xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com toc.xsd"` seems wrong too given that the first value would be the namespace URI of any XML document, only neither your schema snippet seems to define a namespace nor the `toc` root element seems to have any namespace declaration for itself. As I said, for Chrome and local file system access your approach needs the command line option.

Comment: Also `xsl:output method="xml"` to create a root element named `html` which you seem to expect to render something in the browser also seems wrong, you probably want `method="html"` or don't specify a method as with your `html` result root element the browser will use that method if you don't specify one.